# How to use the sdk of iOS5.1 with xcode 4.5.2?

Tags: sdk, ios5.1

I installed Xcode 4.5.2, however I can only find the SDK of iOS 6. How can I use the SDK of iOS 5.1 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot (easily) compile/link against the iOS 5.1 SDK with Xcode 4.5.2. However, you can install the iOS 5.1 Simulator, which allows you to run under the iOS 5.1 SDK. If you really need Xcode plus an earlier SDK, download an earlier version of Xcode. Multiple versions of Xcode can live together on your machine.